# How to get the ID from a dynamic table

Tags: php

I have a website with a table like this : 
[image: my web site exemple]
(all data are fake here) 
I would like that when I click on a switch button, it change the data into my bdd too. to make that I did something like this :

```
echo("<form method = 'POST' action='update.php'>
 <tr>
   <td>$name</td>
   <td>$hasmailbox</td>
   <td>$mailboxstorage GO</td>
   <td>$mail</td>
   <td>$status</td>
   <td>
    <label class='switch'>
     <input id='$id' name='billable' type='checkbox' onChange='this.form.submit()' $billable>
     <span class='slider round'></span>
    </label>
   </td>
   <td>
    <label class='switch'>
     <input type='checkbox' onChange='this.form.submit()' $fulluser>
     <span class='slider round'></span>
    </label>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </form>");
```

Currently, when I click on the switch button, it trigger my php page but it didn't give me the right ID of the line.

code of my current update page :

```
try{
 $id=$_SESSION["_id"];
 $fulluser = $_SESSION["_fulluser"];
 $billable = $_POST["billable"];
}catch(Exception $e){
 echo($e);
}

echo($id);
echo($billable);
echo($fulluser);
```

If I don't get the right ID I will not be able to update my BDD with the new state of my switch button !
Many thanks for your help !

Comment: You might want an `<input type="hidden" value='$id' name="id">` to get the id in `$_POST['id']`

Comment: Don't `try/catch` to check if `$_SESSION` and `$_POST` contains the datas you are looking for. `isset()` is made for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want an `<input type="hidden" value='$id' name="id">` to get the id in $_POST['id'] – Cid

It worked for me.